# Does the multilingual feat allow me to choose a language I don't have access to?

Tags: feats, languages, pathfinder-2e

The Pathfinder 2e [multilingual](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=814) feat says:

> You easily pick up new languages. You learn two new languages, chosen
>   from common languages, uncommon languages, and any others you have
>   access to.

Uncommon character options, including languages, require some special feature to access. For example, Gnome Weapon Training grants access to Gnome weapons.

Does the multilingual feat allow a player to access an uncommon language that they don't have access to? The text of the feat says you can choose from "uncommon languages", it's just surprising to me that a player could get carte blanche access to any language they want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no restriction to common or uncommon languages you have access to; the last clause is likely a reference to rare or secret language options.

Note that the player doesn’t have carte blanche here; a non-Druid could still not learn Druidic for example.

Comment: The definition of rarity on page 13 says that things with the uncommon trait require "special training, [growing] up in a specific culture, or [coming] from a certain part of the world". So it seems that there is a restriction for accessing uncommon languages, because they are uncommon.

Comment: Special training... such as taking a feat? If that’s not what that indicates I don’t know how else you would do it!

Comment: That's the root of the question. The feat doesn't say that you gain access to those languages. I'd contrast it with something like Gnome Weapon Familiarity, which explicitly says "you gain access to all uncommon gnome weapons".

Comment: *Gnome Weapon Familiarity* also doesn’t give the character the weapons, where *Multilingual* does give use of the language; you don’t need access to something you already know.

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah... mechanically, Multilingual calls out Uncommon languages as available, so it overcomes the rules about rarity. I imagine later there will be Rare languages (Drow Sign for instance?) that simple study does not cover